# Connect to a WiFi access point by MAC address

Tags: macos, network, wifi, airport

I have a macOS laptop. To test a WiFi access point, I would like to associate it with a specific access point using its 802.11 MAC address.

Previously this was possible by giving the  `/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Apple80211.framework/Versions/Current/Resources/airport` command the `--associate` flag, but that flag is no longer present.

Is there any way to do this anymore?